# Response from spring controller getting truncated in ui (html)

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, oracle, spring-mvc

I am using angularjs in spring mvc using java and oracle.
I am trying to fetch large amount of data..i got the response correctly from the db and thr response is being sent correctly to the UI as well.
But it gets truncated after 10000 characters.

Can anyone tell why is that happening ...have tried to search a lot but didnt get any answer.Please help.

My controller file--

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllInvoices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Invoice> getAllInvoices() 
    {   
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("inside getAllInvoices Controller");}
        InvoiceServiceImpl invoiceServiceImpl = new InvoiceServiceImpl();
        List<Invoice> response= invoiceServiceImpl.getAllInvoices();
        System.out.println("response contoller-->"+response);
        return (response);
    }
```

My UI js file--

```
  $scope.getAllInvoices = function getAllInvoices() {
    //alert("inside fetchInvoice")
    var promise = $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : 'getAllInvoices',//'fetchInvoice/INV60/209/29-11-17'//+ $scope.invoiceGSTDetails.invId + '/' + 
        //timeout: 1000000,
       // async : 'false'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        alert("response--"+ JSON.stringify(response.data))
        //$scope.taxDetailsShow = false;
        return response.data;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Is it correct at the API response?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: Have you inspect in the browser? Is it shows only the 1000 characters in the code?

Comment: yes i alerted the response in UI and saw it was 10000 char and rest truncated

Comment: can you please console.log(response.data.length)?

Comment: ya it says 77 in the console...and there are 77 items in the db..

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue: request from Angular to Spring Boot using simple http.get() results in the response correctly executed but results are truncated.

Here is an example:

1. My Angular component uses http.get to communicate with Spring backend.
2. Spring Boot uses ORM/Hibernate to map DB entries.
3. Requests between Spring and MariaDB are ok.
4. HTTP requests are correctly executed (all requests are successfully tested using Postman) but not all DB entries are returned to Angular.

I am quite interested if anybody has a solution/ideas.